# Liferay: Which request used send param to two portlet same time?

Tags: liferay, httprequest

I am use Liferay 6.2.

I want send parameter from portlet A to portlet B. But i want portlet B received that parameter too.

Usually use this but does not work:

This is code on portlet A.

PortletURL renderURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, portletBName, themeDisplay.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);

renderURL.setParameter("mvcPath", "/html/carinformation/view_2.jsp");
renderURL.setParameter("carId", car.getId());

Which method can use ? Example code if can , please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a public render parameter. Its a JSR standard for inter-portlet communication.

have a look at this sample portlet https://github.com/mir333/example/ or google for `public render parameter example Liferay` for more examples.

the key things to do is to put this in the portlet.xml for every participating portlet.

`<supported-public-render-parameter>carId</supported-public-render-parameter>`

Then when you have a reader url in the jsp like this:

```
    <portlet:renderURL var="rednerURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/carinformation/view_2.jsp"/>
        <portlet:param name="carId" value="${car.id}"/>
    </portlet:renderURL>
```

Comment: Hi, i try but not enough. when i pass jsp page of portlet B in actionURL of portlet B. portlet A render to this jspPage , not portlet B render to this jspPage. Please help me.

Comment: i added more description in question. ussually call html of portlet A from  portlet B like that.

Comment: Did you make the mvcPath parameter a public render parameter? You can't do that. The public render parameter should be just the carId. The public render parameter is then sent to all portlets that support the given public render parameter.

Comment: I did. So realized cant do that with public render parameter. How can i do with this code:PortletURL renderURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, portletBName, themeDisplay.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);

renderURL.setParameter("mvcPath", "/html/carinformation/view_2.jsp"); renderURL.setParameter("carId", car.getId());

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found out. Just need config a public parameter. On portlet A create PortletURL as above. And on portlet B you can received it normal.